What is the inverse z transform of 1/(2z-1)^2
I have calculated $\frac{1}{\left(2z-1\right)^2}$ by hand, but it gives a different result to that Wolframalpha gives.
Step 1: Write $\frac{1}{\left(2z-1\right)^2}=\frac{1}{4}z^{-1}\cdot\frac{z^{-1}}{\left(1-\frac{1}{2}z^{-1}\right)^2}$
Step 2: First consider the part $\frac{z^{-1}}{\left(1-\frac{1}{2}z^{-1}\right)^2}$
Step 3: Use the known transform $\frac{z^{-1}}{\left(1-z^{-1}\right)^2}\rightarrow ku\left[k\right]$ and that $r^k\cdot u_k\rightarrow U\left(r^{-1}z\right)$, where $r=1/2$ in my case.
Step 4: Calculate the inverse transform, which gives $k\cdot2^{-k}\cdot u\left[k\right]$
Step 5: Now consider the $\frac{1}{4}z^{-1}$ part, which is multiplication by $1/4$ and time delay of $1$, giving $\frac{1}{4}\left(k-1\right)\cdot2^{-k+1}\cdot u\left[k-1\right]=\frac{1}{2}\left(k-1\right)\cdot2^{-k}\cdot u\left[k-1\right]$.
However, Wolframalpha gives the result $\left(k-1\right)\cdot 2^{-k}\cdot u\left[k-1\right]$, which is different by a factor of 2.
What seems to be wrong here? Thanks!
